# Can Google Cloud Speech handle multiple request from the same client at the same time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to transcribe 1000 audios, each 15 minutes long.

I already tried it for one audio and it worked.

So my question is, could I run multiple long transcription commands at the same time without google-cloud-speech failing, or should I do it one-by-one instead?

And if I could run multiple commands at the same time, what is the limit of number of commands google-cloud-speech could handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by submitting a long-running audio processing operation. You could submit 1000 audio files and return immediately, save the process id's in a list, and poll for the operations to check whether they have been completed. This is what google exactly describes in its [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize).

Regarding your question about the API limits, I would suggest you take a look at the speech-to-text [quotas page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas). The request limit is 900 requests per 60 seconds. Moreover, the amount of speech you can process every day is 460 hours. In your specific case, it will probably stay within those limits.